# Is there something fundamentally wrong with this .find function? (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

```
const cleanMongo = (name) => {
        Item.find({ name: name }, (foundItem) => {
            console.log('found item equals', foundItem)
        });
```

For some reason, the .log is always says the search returns with null, when it should be returning with a matching document queried successfully only moments before.

Comment: First param is error, so it should be `Item.find({ name: name }, (error, foundItem) => {`

Comment: "callback has two parameters - an error object (if an error occured) and a cursor object." https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First param is error on `find`'s callback, so it should be

```
Item.find({ name: name }, (error, foundItem) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the parameters correctly , the error should be the [`first parameter`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html),

```
Item.find({ name: name }, (error, foundItem) => {
     console.log('found item equals', foundItem)
});
```